# Help me complete this Differential Geometry equation for a geodesic.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am wondering what happens to the geodesic equation if there is a constant acceleration,$A_3$:
$$\frac{d^2x^\nu}{ds^2}=A_3$$
$$\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}\frac{d x^\beta}{ds}$$
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}\right]=\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}\frac{d x^\beta}{ds}\right]=A_3$$
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{dx^\nu}{d x^\beta}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}\left(\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta \partial x^\alpha}\frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}$$
Using the product rule, we get:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}\frac{d x^\beta}{ds}\right]=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}\frac{d^2 x^\beta}{ds^2}+\frac{\partial^2 x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta \partial x^\alpha}\frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}\frac{d x^\beta}{ds}=A_3$$
This is the part where I need help.  I want to isolate the acceleration term $\frac{d^2 x^\beta}{ds^2}$   and construct a Christoff symbol, so I multiply each side by the inverse of the transform matrix: $\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}^{-1}$
$$\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{ds^2}+\left[\left(\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial^2 x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta \partial x^\alpha}\right]\frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}\frac{d x^\beta}{ds}=\left(\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\right)^{-1}A_3$$
$$\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{ds^2}+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}\frac{d x^\beta}{ds}=\left(\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\right)^{-1}A_3$$
But I'm pretty sure I can't use the same indices when I perform this last operation and the inverse matrix notation just doesn't look right.  Please help me complete this formula with the proper notation (or confirm that the notation is correct).

Comment: Consider editing the title to be a little more informative as to the question's contents. Maybe something like, "Differential equation for constant-acceleration curves in a Riemannian manifold"